# Is the phrase "Only to later realize" correct in usage?

Tags: grammar

I have this sentence:

> Attended ABC college where I topped the English subject in 10th grade (only to later realize that my love for the language couldn’t end there).

Now after 15 years I realize the truth of the parenthesized statement, so how exactly should I state this? "Only to later realize" OR "Only later did I realize". I want to emphasize that period of time and hence prefer retaining the first usage of the phrase. Please correct me if I am grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Since you will find no end of examples of [only to later realize](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22only%20to%20later%20realize%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en) in published books, the question is unclear. Clearly native speakers perceive this construction as grammatical.

Answer (score -1):

"Only to later realize" is an instance of [split infinitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_infinitive).

It's grammatically correct, even though some folks will frown on that construction, which they consider as inelegant.

And so, a more largely accepted phrasing would be to say "only to realize later" instead.

That being said, an equally correct construction pushing more emphasis on the period of time is:

> > Attended ABC college where I topped the English subject in 10th grade, and **realized only later** that my love for the language couldn’t end there.